# Point of inflection with discontinuous second derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

It was given in the Thomas calculus that *at point of inflection second derivative is zero if it's continuous at the point*, but it was also given

> Even if the continuity assumption is dropped it is still true that second derivative is equal to $0$ , provided the second derivative exist.

Can anyone explain the latter with example

Comment: Please provide definition of point of inflection you're working with.

Comment: @Radost a point of infection is a point at which the tangent exist and the concavity of the graph changes